# A question about FactorList[]

Tags: factorization

```
FactorList[24 + 80 x + 102 x^2 + 62 x^3 + 18 x^4 + 2 x^5]
```

> {{2, 1}, {1 + x, 2}, {2 + x, 2}, {3 + x, 1}}

**what does the "1" of "{2,1}" mean?**

[image]

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FactorList.html) _FactorList[poly] gives a list of the factors of a polynomial, together with their exponents._

Answer (score 2):

I think this is an exponent. The answer is: 2*(x+1)^2*(2+x)^2*(3+x)

Comment: but which one does the exponent belong?

Comment: @White0-0 it belongs to the value it is in the list with. Ergo, `{2, 1} -> 2^1` and `{1 + x, 2} -> (1+x)^2`, etc.